# PS2 on a 48" hdtv: composite vs component

Tags: ps2

I've recently dug out my ps2 to replay some games. It looks absolutely terrible on my new tv. As soon as anything moves, the picture gets very blurry and pixelated.

I've read about component video being the best possible quality for the ps2, but I'm having trouble finding a cheap one locally. I was wondering, will it be a noticeable difference on a tv this size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component cable will make a big difference in video quality, it's quite noticeable on my 42" 1080p TV, but the problem you're describing may still remain. The fact that things change when anything moves suggest that you maybe having an issue with your TV's video processing. Check to see if your TV has a game mode that you can enable for the input that you've connected your PlayStation 2 to. Video processing generally doesn't work well with games, and as it can cause a fair bit of lag, most TVs have a mode that disables it.

It shouldn't be too hard to find a multi-system component component cable for sale pretty cheap that supports the PlayStation 2. Also a PlayStation 3 component cable will work, as both consoles use the same AV connector.

Comment: After some more digging, I have indeed found a few cheap component cables that should work. They're all around the same price range, so I'm guessing the quality should be similar. Thanks!

Comment: @IvoCoumans Can you please a comment and share your experience, was the image cleaner with the component cable in your case? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the component cable was an improvement. I borrowed one from a friend's PS3 (mine only had a HDMI cable). However, it turned out that my TV was causing most of the issues due to a setting similar to something like "game mode". I've used the regular cables since. I don't know the settings anymore, since I've gotten a different TV since.